# slow migration from jquery to react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

My company got quite a complex library built with jQuery. All components are rendered by javascript. We most commonly use it as a submodule in other projects. We are considering rewriting this to React but I need some help on how to start. A few questions:

- Is that possible to migrate slowly and use both jQuery and React meanwhile?
- Could you point me to a good reading about the actual advantages of such move?
- Could you please recommend an easy tutorial on how to start that migration?

I know the basics of React, so I don't need help with the code itself but more with how to start and proceed with migration.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be attempting a rewrite (I think "migration" is the wrong word) of your application based on the "hope" that it will be faster/easier to manage. You're basically asking your management to underwrite - and pay for - what is currently a vanity project. You need concrete evidence that a rewrite will bring benefits across the board which you don't currently have.

Comment: Very vague "*with the hope*" and "*I think*" - you need to provide a concrete example that demonstrates the improvement and thus the ROI.  Pick a *small* component and rewrite just that component in React.  Detail how long it took (including the massive learning curve) compared with how long it would take in js/jquery.  Show how you can debug/fix bugs in the implementation.  Show how much faster it runs and how easy it is to implement in projects compared with the js/jquery version. Demonstrate how your team can handle the weekly rewrites of react compared with a stable base such as js/jquery.

Comment: I'm asking you how to start, not how to talk to my management.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your application structure. You need to do a POC by replacing a module/component/screen with the functional equivalent built in React. That will give you a better idea of how to approach this and what the effort might be to address the entire application as well as how to do a phased migration.

Comment: @Igor Is it possible to do it within the existing code (on a separate branch for example, as an experiment) and could you point me to some good tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Again no idea without knowing the details of your application. There is no one size fits all approach to do this. It will be trial and error on your part. I recommend you pick a simple screen and start from there. There are also no tutorials that I am aware of as the approach really depends on your existing application structure and how you want to migrate that to the react equivalent.